# Python module best practices

Tags: python, module, coding-style

Let's say I have a simple module (`foo.py`) like so:

```
import os
import sys

THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT = sys.path

def this_is_a_function():
    print os.name()
```

Now, suppose this that I `import foo`. I would now have the following:

```
>>> dir(foo)
['THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'os', 'sys', 'this_is_a_function']
```

To me, it is distracting and annoying that I can access `foo.os` and `foo.sys` because IMO they shouldn't be exported by module `foo`.

I could add `del sys` to the end of `foo.py`, but is this considered bad practice? Unfortunately, the same cannot be done for `del os`.

Comment: I actually prefer this. In case the main module, which imports foo, does not need os or sys, you don't need to import them there.

Answer (score 0):

If it really bothers you, `import sys as _sys` and so forth.

Comment: That doesn't really change anything... `dir(foo)` would just contain `_sys` instead

Comment: Of course, but users of the module would know it's an implementation detail, not part of the module's interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's good this way. Otherwise, you could have long modules that rely on lots of imports and not keep track of all the imports needed in the main function. I don't really see any issues with foo.py exporting `sys` and `os`.